# Kubuntu 13.10 Black Desktop

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, 13.10, kubuntu-netbook

I upgraded my Kubuntu 13.04 i386 installation on my Acer One Aspire to Kubuntu 13.10 Beta 2. After the upgrade and reboot, the login screen appeared as normal. After logging in, the various "loading" icons appeared, and then the screen went black, except for the mouse cursor. Occasionally, a notification dialog (for system updates) would appear. I could switch to TTY 1 and login there and update, so the netbook was still working. Basically, the desktop was black. There was a known problem with beta 2 relating to this, but did not apply to me, as I had not applied any colour correction. The work-around for this (disabling and re-enabling compositing) did not fix the problem.

I've now fully updated the netbook to 13.10 (via TTY), but the problem persists. How can I fix this? I'd like to avoid installing 13.10 if possible.

**Update:** I booted Kubuntu 13.10 i386 from a live USB and selected "Try Kubuntu". The desktop appeared. I then reinstalled, overwriting `/`, but keeping `/home/`. After rebooting and logging in, the desktop appears black, with only the mouse cursor showing, as before. Pressing Alt-Shift F12 toggles the wallpaper showing, but that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling Kubuntu 13.10 i386 as before, but this time also overwriting/formatting the `\home` partition.